# How do I re-enable stacked tool windows in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have somehow pressed a key combination that has disabled my ability to view two tool windows (Project and Structure) at the same time on the left side of the Android Studio screen.

[image]

I want to be able to visually see both tools at the same time (which was the default until my key combo somehow disabled it) like this:

[image]

I have searched in vain for the magic key combo or menu item to turn this back on. I have tried reloading the default layout configuration, but that does not work. I have tried all the options from the "Window" menu, that also doesn't appear to manage the view for allowing the second tool window you click on to show up nested under the first one.

I remember seeing something about this once on SO but I can't find it.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag and drop the 'Structure' tab from where it is (left pane, but on the top) to the bottom part of the left pane (close to 'Build variants' on your screen).

[Here's the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmzVm.png)

Edit: You can as well just right click the 'Structure' tab -> 'Move to' -> 'Left bottom'.

The problem is that they cannot be both on the top left.